# Using C# 4.8: Most efficient way to remove items matching string patterns from a string array or string list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to remove items from the list that match a collection of string patterns. If needed, I can loop through the list/array of patterns to remove rather than matching all of them at once.

Note: the string patterns are dynamic and we don’t know what will be passed in.
We do know the patterns can have Asterisk and/or Question Marks, and have the same function as in:

System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(, );

Where `?xyz.txt` would find `1xyz.txt`, `2xyz.txt`, but not `12xyz.txt` and not `xyz.txt`

This is what I came up with which does not work.

```
string exclude = "*yf*";
List<string> listRemaining = listAll.Where(x => !listAll.Contains(exclude)).ToList();
```

This is an example of patterns for items to remove from the list:

`*yf*`

`*xName.txt`

`?MyFileName*`

And this is a sample list of strings where we need to remove items matching the 3 patterns above:

```
AyFileName.log
AyFilexName.txt
ByFilexName.log
ByFileName.txt
zMyFileName.log
zMyFileName.txt
SomeFancyFileName.log
SomeFancyFileName.txt
TodayFileName.log
TodayFileName.txt
UglyFileName.log
UglyFileName.txt
```

**Items to be removed?**

Pattern to remove:  `*yf*`

will remove:

```
`SomeFancyFileName.log`
`SomeFancyFileName.txt`
`UglyFileName.log`
`UglyFileName.txt`
```

Pattern to remove:  `*xName.txt`

will remove:
`AyFilexName.txt`

Pattern to remove:  `?MyFileName*`

will remove:
`zMyFileName.log`
`zMyFileName.txt`

Thank you.

Comment: For each string in listAll, iterate over each character in each of the filter strings. If the filter string characters is a '*' skip candidate characters until you encounter the character immediately following it, if it's a '?' then you skip just one character, then if all the following filter string literals match, the listAll candidate matches.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing

Comment: @jwdonahue string is `HelLloWorld`, pattern is `*loWorld`. This string should be matched I guess, but your algorithm won't match them if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yup, obvious hand waving in comment. It wasn't an answer. There's also UNICODE'isms where multiple code points are effectively the same character. Better to use existing glob implementations.

Comment: I don't give explicit correct answers to these kinds of questions, because they tend to be homework problems. It's enough to tickle some nuerons.

Comment: @jwdonahue yeah, I don't have anything wrong with your comment. I just wrote a counterexample so that the author is aware of it. I think anyway your comment might be a good start to solve the problem :)

Comment: @E.Shcherbo, ya I've been down that path before. Written that code in x86 assembler, Pascal, Ada and C, but .NET gives us a rich set of assemblies to chose from. Among them are multiple glob implementations of various quality. It's a lot of work writing a good one.

Comment: Thanks @jwdonahue, I never hear of glob before and it looks very useful.  I already have my list of files (file names) using "System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(, )" which works good as it includes the ? functionality that the client requested.  Now I need a good method to Exclude items matching a set of patterns.  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.  I provide a linq example that doesn't work and was hoping to get a recommendation on now to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be the File globbing as @jwdonahue mentioned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing

But if you want to build your own solution for that, this might be a start.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Filter(string pattern, IEnumerable<string> list) {
    return list.Where(e =>!Match(pattern, e));
}

public static bool Match(string pattern, string input) {
    var modifiedPattern = pattern
        .Replace(@"\", @"\\")
        .Replace(".", @"\.")
        .Replace("*", ".*")
        .Replace("?", ".");
    modifiedPattern = "^" + modifiedPattern + "$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, modifiedPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Which you can call like

```
    var filterPattern = "?MyFileName*";
    var listRemaining = Filter(filterPattern, listAll).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks.  I tried the example above but it did not filter anything.
static void TestFilter()
{
    List<string> listAll = new string[] { "zMyFileName.txt", "zzMyFileName.txt", "FileName.txt"}.ToList();
    var filterPattern = "?MyFilename.log";
    var listRemaining = Filter(filterPattern, listAll).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(listRemaining.Count);
}

Comment: but this works kind of..
private static String WildCardAndQuestionMarkToRegular(String value)
{
    return "^" + Regex.Escape(value).Replace("\\?", ".").Replace("\\*", ".*") + "$";
}

using "?MyFileName.txt" as a filter, it will return "zMyFileName.txt". But I cannot use "?My*" as a filter.  My challenge is using both a question mark and an asterisk in the same filter

Comment: Just adjust the `filterPattern` variable. It should work with both at the same time `?` as also `*`.

Comment: I did, but both lists (listAll and listRemaining) have he same count.  Its hard to show code here, this is the example where it does not work:

static void TestFilter()
{
    List<string> listAll = new string[] { "zMyFileName.txt", "zzMyFileName.txt", "FileName.txt"}.ToList();
    var filterPattern = "?My*";
    var listRemaining = Filter(filterPattern, listAll).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(listRemaining.Count);
}

Comment: Isn't it correct? The `?` represents one wildcard character and the `*` any count of characters.or do you want to get the complementary result? Then remove the `! ` in front of the `Match` call.